# Querying multiple indices by prioritising the indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am querying in multiple indices using [Elasticsearch multi index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html).
But I need to prioritise my query.

For example I query in two indices `index1` and `index2` as

`/index1,index2/_searchq=yourQueryHere`

I want the query to happen in `index2` first and then in `index1.

Comment: Why? Do you want the results of index1 first? Or if you get enough results from index1, the search in index2 is optional or even unnecessary? Or is the result of index1 required for the query in index2?

Comment: I want to give a weightage to `index2` querying than index1.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, there is a need to weight the results by source index. For example, hits in `index1` are more important than the hits coming from `index2` by factor 3 (for example).

There is a [`index_boost`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-index-boost) feature which gives you the ability to create multi index queries weighted by source index.

```
GET /index1,index2/_search 
{
  "indices_boost" : [
    {"index1": 3.0}, 
    {"index2": 1.0}
  ], 
  "query": {...your query goes here...} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. But I don't know it is not working as expected. May be it's because of my data.

Comment: Or your index mapping as mentioned before. have a look at the docs

Comment: I am using suggesters. Do that make any difference?